# Why does my middleware app show invalid session ID shortly after connecting?

Tags: api

I'm using both Zapier and Workato to run some API integrations into my Salesforce org, I appear to be getting `401: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid` errors on both systems.

Only initial connection and for at least a few minutes the connection works and I can successfully query and push data into Salesforce but shortly after both systems return the 401 error. The user password or grants have not been changed, and I don't think its a Zapier and Workato issue as both platforms are experiencing the same issue.

Could someone explain what could be the cause? I suspect its something in Salesforce. Looking at why a session would be invalidated occurs to be only when the app access has been revoked or the password has been changed. Neither of these actions have been completed however so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Did you enable "Lock sessions to IP addresses" in Session Settings? This could cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: This was the reason why, please turn this into an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tools that use a pool of IP addresses will have problems staying logged in when using the security feature "Lock sessions to IP Addresses" found in the Session Security Settings in Setup. This can also happen to devices that roam from network to network. This feature should be disabled unless you absolutely need the extra security.